# Solr - Return random results (Sort by Random)

Tags: solr

In Solr, Whats the best approach to order results by random?, basically needs to pick some records at random.

Comment: Questions has been poorly detailed and there is no exaplation on what user want to achieve and what steps he has carried out so far to achieve this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a [RandomSortField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html). There's an example in the bundled schema.xml in example directory (under `solr`):

```
<dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />
```

Sort your result list by the field `random_<seed>`, where you replace `<seed>` with a randomly generated value (but use the same value if you're paginating through the result, as it will give you a stable sort based on the field name).

Comment: Good working fine. But when index version change this sort order get changed for same key.  Do we have any solution to not use index version in random sort and user only rand key ?

Comment: @PiyushAghera Although its an old post, but did you get the solution to not using index version in randomization so that the logic is independent of index updates?

Comment: @ShreyShivam You can try [modifying RandomSortField](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/e2521b2a8baabdaf43b92192588f51e042d21e97/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.java) and building a custom version of Solr - my guess is [that changing line 86](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/e2521b2a8baabdaf43b92192588f51e042d21e97/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.java#L86) to not consider the docbase or version might be enough.

Comment: @MatsLindh how would one go about doing that? I haven't been able to find any tutorials online.

Comment: I figured it out. It works in single instances, but if using multiple instances and replicas, different random numbers may be generated with the same seed.

Answer (score 0):

In latest Solr, nothing need to do with schema.
Just add below sorting and it will give random result set.

```
...
...

//Below is to get rendom string
$randString = mt_rand();        
$query->addSort('random_'.$randString, $query::SORT_DESC);

...
...
```

Comment: As mentioned in the answer - this is already as an example in the bundled schema. _However_, if you're not using the bundled schema, you'll have to add the field yourself (and type, if necessary).