# Return Solr documents with various types equally

Tags: solr

I currently have an index consisting of various items (e.g. books, dvds, comics and more). I normalized them into documents of the following structure:

```
{ 
   type: "DVD",
   topics: ["romance", "love"]
},
{ 
   type: "COMIC",
   topics: ["war", "world war 2", "love"]
},
...
```

Now whenever I perform a search on for example "topics:love", a whole lot of my documents match and receive the same score.

In the results, big chunks of the same type seem to follow each other:

```
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - COMIC
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD
score 2 - DVD

score 1 - DVD
score 1 - DVD
score 1 - DVD
score 1 - DVD
score 1 - COMIC
score 1 - COMIC
...
```

Is there a way to force Solr to interleave/alternate the various results by type to make a more interesting experience for users when browsing? Or perhaps I need to tackle this problem another way?

The provided example is just an example. In the real scenario, results of the same type often span hundreds of documents before another type appears with the same score.

Comment: Could you use a random value as the second sort? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234102/solr-return-random-results-sort-by-random

Comment: @MatsLindh This might be an elegant solution, I'll try it out tomorrow and report back with the results!

Comment: @MatsLindh This worked. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.