# Randomize result set between the brands in solr

Tags: solr

I have collection of 2.5 L product which have only 3 brands.Which are divided in like 75%,20%,10% ration.
Now whenever I perform a query to solr,I always use to get product from 75% brand collection.I want to randomize result set so that other brand's product also come in top list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr - Return random results (Sort by Random)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234102/solr-return-random-results-sort-by-random)

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 kinds of boosts.**

1. **Index-time boosts**

   > Index-time boosts boosts are applied when adding documents, and apply to the entire document or to specific fields.
2. **Query-time boosts**

   > Query-time boosts are applied when constructing a search query, and apply to specific fields

Let your brand's are brand_a, brand_b and brand_c and brand field name is brand
Make brand_a boost by 1, brand_b boost by 2 and brand_c boost by 3

**Query-time boosts :**

```
brand:"brand_a"^1 OR brand:"brand_b"^2 OR brand:"brand_c"^3
```

**Index-time boosts :**

```
<add>
  <doc boost="1">
    <field name="brand">brand_a</field>
    ...
  </doc>
  <doc boost="2">
    <field name="brand">brand_b</field>
    ...
  </doc>
  <doc boost="3">
    <field name="brand">brand_c</field>
    ...
  </doc>
</add>
```

You can use any one of the above depending upon your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you really want to ignore relevance completely and just return random products that (100% ?) match user search? You can have a random field to do so, but I suspect that's a short term solution.

Would you prefer instead to - for example - group the results by brand and then return top X results from each brand? Solr has [Collapse and Expand](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collapse+and+Expand+Results) functionality for that.