# Solr query without computing score

Tags: solr

Is it possible to run dismax query without computing score? I just need this to make some tests - what is influence of score computing in Solr searching performance.

For now i have dismax query like this:

`{
  limit : 10,
  params:{
    defType:"dismax",
    q:"${query}",
    q.op:"${operator}",
    qf:"${fields}",
    indent:"off"
  }
}`

Is there some easy way to achieve what i want? Maybe i should use filter query but how can i specify operators and use query phase from user as it is without any processing in fq?

Answer (score 0):

You can [introduce different query parser through localparams](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams), so something like:

```
q=*:*&fq={!type=dismax qf='${fields}'}${query}
```

.. should work. If these are not local variables that you expand yourself, the syntax might be slightly different.

Comment: I am not sure how this should help me. My query works fine, all i need is make same query but without score computing - just return some first/random results matching my query. Those variables in my query are JMeter variables.

Comment: A `fq` clause wouldn't affect score - and the main query would match all documents and not contribute any score (`*:*`), which would result in the documents being returned in lucene index order by default. If you want to return the results in random order, you can [sort by a random field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234102/solr-return-random-results-sort-by-random). You can also sort by a constant scoring function query as a hack around score (i.e. `abs(0)` or something like that).