# SOLR dynamic fields and random filtering

Tags: sorting, random, solr, filter

I would like to perform a random sort of data coming from database using SOLR.
I found that SOLR has already a dynamicField that I can use with random field type :

```
<types>
   ...
   <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" />
  ... 
</types>
<fields>
    ...
   <dynamicField name="random*" type="random" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
    ...
</fields>
```

But I don't understant how to fill the random* column. My data are issues from data import using SQL query.

Must I fill the column in db-data-config.xml and in which way ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr - Return random results (Sort by Random)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234102/solr-return-random-results-sort-by-random)

Comment: You don't fill the field with any values. The random field generates a random value each time it's being asked for the field value internally by Solr. The field names is used as the seed (i.e. to get the same order, use the same field name - which is why they're usually defined as a wildcard field, so that you can add your own seed to the field name). And a "dynamic field" is just a wildcarded name for a regular field, not a special fieldtype.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have reason. I wasn't understant that it is so simple :) You add the above lines and after that you call solr with sort parameters equal to the column random_somePettern desc et this work perfect

Comment: Just do you know if we can limi the size of the pattern after random*

Comment: That will be the responsibility of the code you're using to call Solr.

Comment: Thanks, I understand