# solr search sort by rand within same score

Tags: sorting, random, solr

I am using solr 6.3 i want to sort documents by rand within the same scores

Please see the result response :

```
{
  "numFound": 9796,
  "start": 0,
  "maxScore": 4.813048,
  "docs": [
    {
      "product_slno": "8343676",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.813048
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "9272399",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.813048
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "9117918",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.813048
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "11992571",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.813048
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "12226220",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.813048
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "12239015",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.813048
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "228513",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.6070313
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "382382",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.6070313
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "591419",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.6070313
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "11992574",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.6070313
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "12067342",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.6070313
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "12102172",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.6070313
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "12116777",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.6070313
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "12125565",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.6070313
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "4462552",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.424822
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "6666626",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.424822
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "7036941",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.424822
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "7833234",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.424822
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "7552192",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.424822
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "8757321",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.424822
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "9207159",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.424822
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "9978281",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.424822
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "11642035",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.424822
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "12294941",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 4.424822
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "12313470",
      "product_name": "non-basmati rice",
      "score": 4.424822
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "5457576",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.2188053
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "6666629",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.2188053
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "7552189",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.2188053
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "11476797",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.2188053
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "11642034",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.2188053
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "12209560",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.2188053
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "12230206",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.2188053
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "12233053",
      "product_name": "basmati rice",
      "score": 4.2188053
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "182609",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 1.7452564
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "158848",
      "product_name": "non basmati parboiled rice",
      "score": 1.7452564
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "8439880",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 1.7452564
    },
    {
      "product_slno": "10035413",
      "product_name": "non basmati rice",
      "score": 1.7452564
    }
  ]
}
```

we have multiple documents for scores "4.813048" ,"4.6070313", "4.424822", "4.2188053", "1.7452564" i want random sort within same scores.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by multiple entries - ie. first search by score, then by regular random search. See [Solr - Return random results (Sort by Random)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25252121/137650)
 for how to order a result set randomly.

```
sort=score desc,random_1234 asc
```

Where `random_` is defined as `<dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />`.

Change the value of `1234` to a random value when making the query to Solr.

Comment: hi, i'm getting the following error after implementing sor order by rand 
str name="msg">Can't determine a Sort Order (asc or desc) in sort spec 'score,random_1234', pos=17</str>
  <int name="code">400</int>

Comment: below is my solr query

Comment: <str name="fl">catalog_paid_status,product_related_kword,product_detail_status</str>
<str name="group.limit">4</str>
<str name="start">0</str>
<str name="sort">score,random_450</str>
<str name="group.ngroups">true</str>
<str name="rows">34</str>
<arr name="bq">
<str>(product_detail_status:1)^20</str>
<str>(catalog_paid_status:14)^2.3</str>
<str>(catalog_paid_status:12)^2</str>
</arr>
<str name="q">(product_related_kword:(basmati) AND product_related_kword:"rice+00")</str>
<str name="defType">edismax</str>
<str name="group.field">member_id</str>
<str name="group">true</str>

Comment: You might have to give the sort direction / order - `sort=score desc,random_1234 asc`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using solr Suggester lookupImpl as `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory` , it's working fine the only issue I am not able to resolve is the fact I want exact search keyword display on top.
i.e if I search "Leather bags" then that particular keywords should display on top but it is showing "mens leather bags", "ladies leather bags" after that it is showing "Leather bags". But I want "Leather bags" to display on top.

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">mySuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str> 
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">search_keyword</str>

<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
</lst>     
</searchComponent>
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743827/solr-suggester-blendedinfixlookupfactory-exact-match-problem